# Accessing custom XResources colors with X11

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I'm just starting my first ever program using the X11 library. To start, I'm just trying to access the colors from the user's color-scheme as defined in `xrdb`. For example, in my `~/.Xresources` I have things like:

```
*color8:     #073642
*color0:     #002b36
```

I've also verified that these colors show up when I run `xrdb -query`.  In my C program so far I have:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xresource.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay (0);
    XrmDatabase xrdb = XrmGetDatabase (display);
    XrmValue v;
    Colormap cmap = DefaultColormap (display, DefaultScreen (display));
    XColor screenColor;
    XColor exactColor;

    if (! XAllocNamedColor (display, cmap "color0", &screenColor, &exactColor))
        printf ("ERROR\n");

   printf ("%u %u %u\n", screenColor.red, screenColor.green, screenColor.blue);

   return 0;
}
```

But this errors. So what am I missing? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use `xrdb -merge` or somesuch for the X server to see the values.

Comment: Right,  done that. To be clear,  these custom colors show up when I do `xrdb -query`

Comment: Color0 is not a named color, it"s a key in the resource database. You need to explicitly fetch the corresponding value from xrdb and then allocate a color with it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? What in my code needs to change?

Comment: `XrmDatabase xrdb = ...` The value of `xrdb` is the **only** effect of that statement. If you are not using it, you have called `XrmGetDatabase` for nothing. So your next task is to figure out what `XrmDatabase` actually is and how to use it. Hint: look at `XrmGetResource`, it's the function you will probably need to call.

Comment: I had also tried getResource, but couldn't deduce the appropriate class and type arguments.

Comment: You choose class more or less arbitrarily. You may try `"*"` (any class). The type is returned from the function, you don't need to deduce it. Google `xrmgetresource color`, you will get some instructive code examples.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access parameters set in an Xresource file loaded by `xrdb`, you need to

```
xrdb = XrmGetStringDatabase(XResourceManagerString(display));
```

instead of `XrmGetDatabase(...)`. Hope that addresses (lately) your question.